# PushState requires two "go back" but then "go forward" will stop working

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I have a very rudimentary SPA built in vanilla JS. There are two buttons that the user can use to navigate between pages, for example:

```
buttonProfile.addEventListener("click", function () {
  window.history.pushState({}, "", "profile/");
  var updatePage = new Event("update-page");
  dispatchEvent(updatePage);
});
```

Somewhere in the app, I have an event listener that listens to `update-page` to refresh the content that needs to be refreshed (without ever reloading the page) based on the current URL. Everything works fine.

However, I noted two odd behaviours:

- If the user starts on Page A and then moves to Page B, the user will need to go back twice (button on the browser) in order to go back to Page A.
- If the user goes back from Page B to Page A, once they are back to Page A the "forward" button on the browser will become greyed out.

**EDIT**

In case it helps, I noted I have the same issue when I use other people's SPAs that have a similar implementation. See this simple demo for example: [DEMO](https://zathio-vanilla-spa.netlify.app/) | [CODE](https://github.com/zathio/vanilla-spa)

Steps to reproduce:

- Click on About, then Contact, then again About, then again Contact.
- Now, if you press Back once you'll go back to About. However, if you press it again you'll stay on About. You'll have to press it again to move to Contact and once you do, the Forward button will be disabled.

EDIT 2

I just realize that both my site and the site I posted above work fine when I run my browser in Incognito. There must be some other problem with my Chrome (though I have no idea what).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found it. It was the [Matter official Chrome extension](https://hq.getmatter.app/web-extension). Not sure what exactly caused the issue though.